# Using Table to Assign Values for the Index

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to assign values for the two indexes at the same time. For example:

```
Table[x + y, {x, {1, 2, 3}}, {y, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

will give me an output of:

```
{{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

I'd like to have an output using `{{x,y} = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}` to produce

```
{2,4,6}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `Plus @@@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}`

Comment: `Total /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}`

Comment: Also `Total[lst,{2}]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you must use a single iterator variable in `Table`, but you can "unpack" its value into multiple variables later.

```
Table[
  Block[{x, y}, 
    {x, y} = i; 
    x + y
  ], 
  {i, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}}
]
```

Instead of unpacking, you can also insert the values into the argument of a function directly,

```
Table[Plus @@ i, {i, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}}]
(* {3, 5, 7} *)

Table[(#1 + 2 #2 &) @@ i, {i, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}}]
(* {5, 8, 11} *)
```